# How do I upsert all the rows from one table into another table using Postgres?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I am working in Python, using Pandas to pull data from a TSV, convert it to a data frame, then syncing that data frame to a temp table in postgres using df.to_sql. That process works great.

However, once that table exists, I want to move all the rows from that table to the permanent table. The two tables will always be identical. The permanent table has a unique index, so if the id already exists it should update the row instead.

Here is my attempt to upsert all rows from one table to another:

```
WITH moved_rows AS (
  DELETE FROM my_table_tmp a
  RETURNING a.*
)
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT * FROM moved_rows
ON CONFLICT ("unique_id") DO
  UPDATE SET
    Field_A = excluded.Field_A,
    Field_B = excluded.Field_B,
    Field_C = excluded.Field_C
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, I get this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column excluded.field_a does not exist
LINE 10:           Field_A = excluded.Field_A,
                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "excluded.Field_A".
```

But in fact, that column does exist. What am I missing here? I've tried removing Field_A from the set and then I get the same error with Field_B.

Comment: The error message does not match the displayed query. Please show the statement you actually executed. Declare your version of Postgres. And show the exact table definition: `CREATE TABLE my_table ... `

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've edited it now. I obscured the names just to make it simpler but missed those two refs. Thanks for pointing out @ErwinBrandstetter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here - the issue is that Postgres ignores capitalization unless it's quoted.

This was not clear in the example I posted because I obscured the naming of the fields I was working with. I've updated them now to show the issue.

In order to fix this you need to wrap your field names with double quotes. E.g. `"Field_A" = excluded."Field_A"`